# How to apply or remove part of text of condition in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentProc
    @deptId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Student
    WHERE age > 12 
      AND deptId = @deptId
END
```

When the `@deptId = 0`, is there a way to get all departments, and when `@deptId = number` to filter by `@deptId`?

Comment: IF... ELSE should be an easy one

Comment: Search "catch-all" or "kitchen sink" queries; you'll find the solution you need then.

Comment: Can you just try this: `WHERE age > 12 AND (@deptId = 0 OR deptId = @deptId)` - does that work?

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you need on zero condition return all departments for age > 12 - correct?
use "case" :

```
declare @student Table (id int identity (1,1), age int null, deptid int null)

insert @student (age, deptid) values
(10, 0),(10, 1),(10, 2),
(11, 0),(11, 1),(11, 2),
(15, 0),(15, 1),(15, 2),
(20, 0),(20, 1),(20, 2)

declare @deptId int = 2
    
SELECT 
    * 
FROM @Student
WHERE age > 12 
    AND 
        deptid = case @deptId when 0 then deptId
    else @deptId end


--when parameter zero:
set @deptid = 0

SELECT 
    * 
FROM @Student
WHERE age > 12 
    AND 
        deptid = case @deptId when 0 then deptId
    else @deptId end
```

results would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentProc
    @deptId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Student
    WHERE age > 12 
      AND deptId = Case When @deptId = 0 Then deptId Else @deptId End
END
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

when the @deptId is 0, then don't use the column in **where** condition at all to avoid un-necessary computation (because you want all the departments anyways). Use if else instead.

```
if(@deptID = 0)
begin
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE age > 12
end

else
begin
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE age > 12 and deptId = @deptID
end
```